# Running a java web application in IIS

Tags: java, iis, isapi

Has anybody found a way to run a Java web application within IIS?  It seems to me it should be entirely possible to write an ISAPI plugin (is that the right word?) that integrates Jetty or a custom servlet container with IIS.  The benefit of this is that a lot of great high end Java applications like Jira require separate infrastructure for an otherwise all Microsoft shop.

Comment: closely related to [Lightweight servlet engine for serving java application via IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1344289/)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you will find of use the following two articles

1. [Use Microsoft's Internet Information
   Server as a Java servlet engine](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2000/jw-0616-iis.html?page=3)
2. [Java + ISAPI + Jetty = JSP on IIS](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/codesharp/java-isapi-jetty-jsp-on-iis-27718)

Comment: The first link is from the year 2000

Comment: This is an old answer for its time. Today all readers should check HttpPlatformHandler in another answer, which is the latest from Microsoft itself, empowering both IIS and Azure.

Comment: @frenchie which is now 19+ years ago

Answer (score 11):

Running JVM inside IIS worker process currently is a bad idea. I suggest you to use solution from this article instead: [Deploying Java Servlet applications on Windows with IIS](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/deploying-java-servlet-applications-on-windows-with-iis/)

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft has recently released (2015 Q1) HttpPlatformHandler module for IIS 8+ that lets you host java (or node/ruby applications etc), on IIS.

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/02/04/announcing-the-release-of-the-httpplatformhandler-module-for-iis-8/

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Java EE cannot be hosted in IIS. To host Java EE Application you need at least Servlet container or a full Java EE container which is not supported by IIS. Although, some plugin might be able to do so.

As for your reference, below link is Java EE compatibility by oracle:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html

Comment: IIS can be used as a front end reverse proxy for any other web servers including Java EE application servers. Thus, while "is not supported by IIS" is true, it is still possible to run a Java web app behind IIS.