# how to run .jar file on IIS

Tags: java

I've opened a webserver using IIS on my computer in order to host my multiplayer game.
I've build the server in java and wish to run it on my server so users from different computer can play on it for testing.
Do I need to run it in a webhost or just run as is from netbeans?

Comment: How did you write the server? Using servlets? How do the clients communicate with the server? IIS is not a servlet container. And if HTTP is not used to communicate between the clients and the server, you don't need any web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have write applet then you dont need any server...just create simle html with your applet
If you use jsp or servlets, then you need servlets container...look at this
[Running a java web application in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256084/running-a-java-web-application-in-iis)