# Hosting Java Web Project on IIS

Tags: java, iis, hosting, webproject

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running a java web application in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256084/running-a-java-web-application-in-iis)

I have a web project created and running fine on MyEclipse.
Can I host this on IIS Server? If so, do I need to have any plug-in?
Please tell me the proceadure to do so..
Thanks,
Kavya.

Thanks. But I already have an integrated Tomcat in MyEclipse. Can I make this run on IIS, so that it responds to the requests from my web project at runtime??

Hope, [Running a java web application in IIS] would be usefull.
But I am not much exposed to this Deployment stuff & understand the linked documents so easily...
Could you please guide me to start on with it?
Your help means a lot to me.
Thanks..

---

Seems there is no place for new learners here. Everyone cannot be expert in everything. More over there can be similar questions but the consequences might be different. Please give some time for people to put in their thoughts and let us understand things. The community people are not trying to encourage the involvement of new users. I am experiencing it for the 3rd time & thats disgusting....

Anyhow thanks for making it realize.......