# System.out.println in IIS

Tags: java, iis

If a java application running on IIS has System.out.println() where do these calls go. When on tomcat application server it will generally go into a console. Is there such console with IIS?

Comment: Err since when does IIS run java applications? Must have missed something (havent used IIS for years)..

Comment: Think that you can do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256084/running-a-java-web-application-in-iis regardless may not be a good idea

Comment: Its Microstrategy which runs on IIS as an aspx application. Which is powered by java

Comment: No, you should probably look into logging...whatever a good logging approach is for Java-on-IIS.