# how to deploy Spring boot application in IIS

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, iis, deployment

I have a [Spring boot](https://github.com/ramram43210/Java_Spring_2019/tree/master/JavaEE_2019/SpringBoot_ExternalTomcat/HelloWorld) application, If I want to run that application locally we can run with `spring-boot:run` Or by just executing the main class our project is ready to work. But here I want to deploy the same on IIS Server.

I have an angular app, by just adding the path and running `ng build --prod` is sufficient to run in the IIS but when coming to java I am confused to run the application in IIS.

I dont think so it will work with `spring-boot:run` as it is using internal tomcat server, But in the IIS how do we need to deploy this application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a java web application in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256084/running-a-java-web-application-in-iis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a java based application so it is not recommended to deploy in iis.you could use a docker container to run the application and then use a reverse proxy to redirect the request to that API.

Reference link:

https://github.com/jonashackt/ansible-windows-docker-springboot

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world/ba-p/846222

Comment: Hi, the first link stopped working and it is showing "Page not found".

Comment: @AmjadAbujamous please check the updated link