# run servlet on iis server

Tags: iis, servlets

how can i run servlet in IIS server

Comment: Possible dup of [Lightweight servlet engine for serving java application via IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1344289/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install an [apache tomca](http://tomcat.apache.org/)t on the machine and connect it to your IIS using the ajp connector like descibed in the [IIS howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html)