# it is possible to run JSP files on IIS Server

Tags: java, iis, jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lightweight servlet engine for serving java application via IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344289/lightweight-servlet-engine-for-serving-java-application-via-iis)

It is possible to run JSP files, let's say Struts 1, on IIS Server?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lightweight servlet engine for serving java application via IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1344289/), [Running a java web application in IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2256084/)

Comment: Here is a description of how to use IIS with Tomcat to accomplish this: [Tomcat IIS HowTo](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/tomcat-iis-howto.html)

Answer (score 5):

David Wang wrote a post on the MSDN blogs titled "[How does JSP work on IIS?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/david.wang/how-does-jsp-work-on-iis)" that addresses why JSP can't be run directly under IIS 5.0 and 6.0. The short version is that IIS doesn't run any dynamic content directly, it requires an add-on for it (even ASP.Net). The article mentions a popular add-on to use for servlets is [isapi_redirect](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc-archive/jk2/jk/iishowto.html), which shunts the request to Tomcat for handling (since isapi_redirect is an IIS add-on, IIS still handles communication with the client).

Comment: i read this link but i'm wondering what add-on i need. I would prefer to answer someone who has experience in this. Thanks

Comment: You would have to get Tomcat's ** isapi_redirect** (as per link).

Answer (score 0):

Not without a servlet/JSP engine of some kind.