# deploy a GWT site with aRPC servlet on IIS

Tags: iis, gwt, deployment

is it possible to deploy a gwt site which calles a java servlet on an IIS?

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: I think so. Have you had a look at Jetty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344289/lightweight-servlet-engine-for-serving-java-application-via-iis) discusses servlet engines for IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JK ISAPI plugin to redirect servlet requests to tomcat (assuming you are using tomcat). Then on the gwt client side u can use either Requestbuilder or something as simple as `Window.Location.replace("/IISUrl")` to send the request to IIS.