# Developing for IIS and IBM Websphere

Tags: iis, websphere

My company is looking to develop a web product that will need to run on both Websphere and IIS.  Ideally, we would like to use the same framework for both, but I am currently ignorant of the options, if there are any.  On IIS, we would most likely use ASP MVC, and JSP on Websphere.  Is there some common technology we could use on both platforms?

Answer (score 2):

IIS is a web server. Websphere (or what just the term Websphere commonly refers to) is an application server, Websphere Application Server (WAS). IIS would be more comparable to IHS (IBM HTTP Server) or Apache HTTP Server.

So the answer to "Is there some common technology we could use on both platforms" is probably JSP since WAS is mostly just a Java application server.

A reference for running JSP on IIS [Lightweight servlet engine for serving java application via IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344289/lightweight-servlet-engine-for-serving-java-application-via-iis)

Here is a more detailed discussion on application vs web servers 
[What is the difference between application server and web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936197/what-is-the-difference-between-application-server-and-web-server)

A more general note: Getting the same application to run exactly the same in both environments will likely be a difficult task for any moderately interesting application.

Answer (score 0):

What would be truly common to both is HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. That is, client-side technologies rather than server frameworks. So I'd recommend at least considering one of the JavaScript MVC frameworks. [TodoMVC.com](http://todomvc.com/) compares several of them.